# <button>label disabled in angular template

Tags: angular

I created an angular project, and generated a component. But when I add  label in the template. It disabled like this.
[image: cut from my browser]

my html template:

```
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<button>button</button>
<br>
<br>
<button type="button">button</button>
<br>
<br>
<button type="submit">button</button>
```

Can anyone teach me how to fix this problem. Thank you.

Comment: This is not appearing as disabled. It seems that you have some css writter for button element. That ta why it is appearing like this. Do inspect elements and see if there is any css attached with this buttons. Try remove those css. Default style of button should show after that.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks pal. It probably because the .css file I imported before. Now its worked.